# UML model element versus executable UML model element

Tags: uml

How can i build an executable model in UML?

is it differ from UML model element used while drawing class,SD,...etc

Answer (score 1):

By model element, I assume you mean some kind of UML notation like class, state, activity, etc. The graphical notation doesn't change that much when you use it in an executable context, but the underlying meanings (semantics) may change. To make the notation executable, you need a set of semantics that establish executable behavior on some subset of the UML notation. (Once you start thinking execution, you don't need everything). In the book Executable UML: A Foundation for Model Driven Architecture, Mellor/Balcer, Addison-Wesley 2002 (which I highly recommend), such a set of semantics is defined. If you want to see examples of Executable UML models and how they can be translated to code with open source tools check out Models to Code (with no mysterious gaps), Starr/Mangogna/Mellor, 2017. You may also want to take a look at executableuml.org and xtuml.org.